# How to solve this type of series?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, string-theory, regularization

This series is from the book Quantum field theory in curved spaces by Birrell and Davies pp 95, use of Green's functions. My problem is how from 4.22 to 4.23 they are getting. We have to use some appropriate regulator since the sum is not absolutely convergent.

[image].

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{z\in S}\sum_nn^{-1}z^n=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{z\in S}\ln(1-z)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\prod_{z\in S}(1-z)$$with $S:=\{e^{\pm2\pi i\Delta u/L},\,e^{\pm2\pi i\Delta v/L}\}$. Now use$$\ln(1-e^{i\theta})(1-e^{-i\theta})=\ln(2-e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})=\ln[2(1-\cos\theta)]=\ln\left(4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right).$$It looks like Eq. (4.23) has introduced a prefactor of $\frac12$; hopefully, a larger excerpt would indicate why. (Either that, or Eq. (4.22)'s use of $+\operatorname{c.c.}$, which sounds like the operation $w\mapsto w+\overline{w}$, was meant to be $w\mapsto(w+\overline{w})/2=\Re w$.)

Comment: Yes it's the extra complex conjugate. Thank you